# matlab retrieve elements in a vector corresponding to matrix of indexes

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a vector `v`.
I also have a matrix `M` of size `T`x`N` with each column corresponding to `T` indices of `v`.
For example:  `M(:,1)` is the set of indices `[1,2,12,5,4]` (here `T` = 5).

I want to have a matrix `O` of size `T`x`N` with `O(:,i) = v(M(:,i))` for all `i`.
Is there a way to do that without using for loops ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Very easy: just use

```
O = v(M);
```

Example with `T=3`,  `N=4`:

```
>> v = (10:10:50).'
v =
    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
>> M = randi(5,T,N)
M =
     5     3     5     3
     2     3     1     4
     2     4     5     3
>> O = v(M)
O =
    50    30    50    30
    20    30    10    40
    20    40    50    30
```